# How can I allow two-finger scrolling over an HTML canvas element while allowing one-finger drawing?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, touch

I am attempting to make a canvas drawing app with a fixed size canvas - but with the ability to scroll around the canvas to draw on different points that may not be visible based on the user's screen size.

It scrolls as I would like it to on desktop, but I am trying to implement two finger scrolling on mobile.

http://jsbin.com/qugabuh/edit

In my touch-drawing functions, I tried the following:

```
const startTouch = function(e) {
  if (e.targetTouches.length < 2) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX + content.scrollLeft;
    y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - 34 + content.scrollTop;
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  }
};

const moveTouch = function(e) {
  if (e.targetTouches.length < 2) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX + content.scrollLeft;
    y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - 34 + content.scrollTop;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};
```

This seems to work okay on my Android tablet (although sometimes lines will draw if I don't lift both fingers off at the exact same time), but not at all on my iPhone.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @JayPatel did you find anything that works?

Comment: @JayPatel I believe so, but it's been a long time and I can't say for sure. If I did, it exists somewhere here: github.com/CollaBoard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll vertically with two fingers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62776956/scroll-vertically-with-two-fingers)

Answer (score 0):

Try use a flag to control start event touch.

```js
    const startTouch = function(e) {
        if (e.target === canvas && e.touches.length === 1) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX + content.scrollLeft;
            y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - 34 + content.scrollTop;
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            
            drawable = true;
        }else{
            drawable = false;
        }
    };
```

Look:
https://codepen.io/Luis4raujo/pen/RwoZVXE

Comment: The CodePen doesn't work and the context of `moveTouch` is missing. I recommend adding it.