# Scroll vertically with two fingers

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, scroll, safari

I'm working on a sketch web application (using angular) and, as the one finger gesture is used to draw, I would like to be able to **scroll vertically** in the sketch content **using two fingers**.

When a try to scroll with two fingers, safari exits the current tab and show the list of opened tabs. I can cancel this behaviour by calling `preventDefault()` on the `TouchEvent` if `e.touches.length > 1` but (obviously) that doesn't scroll the content. I could, of course, implement a solution that would dynamically scroll after calling `e.preventDefault()`, but that's a bit tricky.

I would like to know if someone knows an easier/better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Hi, if you could provide the relevant code, we could be able to help you. Now it is virtually impossible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I implement a basic solution based on the `touchmove` and `touchstart` events.

```js
let lastTouchY;

element.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) =>
{
  if (event.touches.length === 2)
  {
    event.preventDefault();

    lastTouchY = event.touches[0].clientY;
  }
});

element.addEventListener('touchmove', (event) =>
{
  if (event.touches.length === 2)
  {
    event.preventDefault();

    const delta = lastTouchY - event.touches[0].clientY;
    lastTouchY = event.touches[0].clientY;

    element.scrollTop += delta;
  }
});
```

### JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/r7hkmaeo/84/

Comment: Can you please provide this as a jsfiddle example?